# How to set single attribute on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I have to dynamically create an Anchor tag that I am adding a Foundation aspect to. One of the elements is called "data-tooltip" that Foundation uses.

If I'm trying to create the following row, how do I create the "data-tooltip" element?

**what I've epected**

```
<a data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true">FOO</a>
```

**how I generate the element**

```
var artworkColumn = document.createElement("a");
artworkColumn.setAttribute("aria-haspopup", "true");
```

I've seen ways in JQuery to do this, but since the "a" element does not exist, I can't use the methods described here on StackOverflow.

Thanks
Steve

Comment: You're already doing it ?

Comment: The usual way of doing this is, artworkColumn.setAttribute("data-tooltip", null).  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3):

Just do the exact same thing you did for `aria-haspopup`, but set the value to an empty string:

`artworkColumn.setAttribute("data-tooltip", '');`

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQVdQL

I think the thing that might be throwing you off is that inspecting the element will not show you the result you expect, but if you print out the element to the console you will see that it does in fact have the properties you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the following element this way **exactly** and **existing** on your page as an element in the DOM:

```
<a data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true">FOO</a>
```

```js
    var artworkColumn = document.createElement("a");
    artworkColumn.setAttribute("aria-haspopup", "true");
    artworkColumn.setAttribute("data-tooltip", "");
    artworkColumn.innerHTML = "FOO";
    document.body.appendChild(artworkColumn);
```

> If your'e looking for functional results refer to the following portion of this answer:

---

After creating a node/element you must append it to DOM.

Also, I think when you are dealing with a boolean value, you actually don't include the quotes (true instead of "true", because anything in quotes is a String type and a Boolean type is not a String).

You can use `setAttribute()` to create or `dataset` to set a `data-*` attribute, remember to change the name when invoking it with `dataset` (ex. `data-tooltip` would be `tooltip` in your JS code, using `dataset`.) I recommend using `setAttribute()`

Here's an [article that'll set you straight on the `data-*`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

```js
// Using setAttribute()
var artworkColumn = document.createElement("a");
artworkColumn.setAttribute("aria-haspopup", true);
artworkColumn.setAttribute("data-tooltip", "");
artworkColumn.setAttribute("href", "http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/b19cddd2-1b79-4679-b6d3-1bf8d7235b89/93794aec-3f17-47a4-8801-a2716a9c4598_560_420.jpg");
artworkColumn.innerHTML = "Starry Night, Vincent Van Gogh";
document.body.appendChild(artworkColumn);

// Using dataset
var art = document.getElementById('artwork1');
var tip = art.dataset.tooltip;
console.log('tip: '+tip);

// Use DevTools in the browser to test both methods.  
// To see the anchor object, artworkColumn: 

   /* F12 then find the Element tab to see the new link,
      there's also an empty "Link" under the image. */

// To test to see if the data-tooltip was created:

   /* F12 then find the Console tab,
      you'll see the log: 'tip: circa. 1889' */
```

```css
a { color: red; text-decoration: none; font-size: 42px;}
a:hover {color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; }
a:before { content: 'Link: ';}
```

```html
<figure id="artwork1" data-tooltip="circa. 1889">
  <img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/b19cddd2-1b79-4679-b6d3-1bf8d7235b89/93794aec-3f17-47a4-8801-a2716a9c4598_560_420.jpg" alt=""/>
  </figure>
```

Comment: How does appending it to the DOM add the `data-tooltip` attribute?

Comment: Updated answer to account for any `data-*` to be accessed with  JS: `setAttribute()` `getAttribute()` and `dataset`.

Comment: I'm still unsure why you say he must append it to the DOM? Of course he has to do that if he wants it rendered in the browser, but that seems totally unrelated to the question of how to add the attribute.

Comment: I have a tendency to answer a question as it pertains to OP's expected issues that'll most likely occur. Giving the exact info to OP's request isn't always what one needs in the long run. Giving a novice the knowledge to set attributes to a newly created element and not informing OP about appending it to DOM is like giving someone a paddle and no boat.

Comment: I also like to give additional information that will help them in the overall application, but I try not to suggest that it's the main thing that answers the question.